# The number of $2$-Sylow subgroups in $S_4 \times S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

The number of $2$-Sylow subgroups is $p=1+2k$, where $p$ divides $\left|S_4×S_3\right| = 2^43^2=144$. Then $p$ divides $9$. So $p=0$ or $4$. Which one do I choose?

Comment: $p$ divides $9$. So, $p=0$ or $p=4$... WHat do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

Note that each factor in the direct product has $3$ Sylow $2$-subgroups (because they are not normal) so there are at least $9$ distinct maximal $2$-subgroups, which must be all of them since the number must divide $9$.

Comment: I think you need to use the fact that neither $S_3$ nor $S_4$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup, in order to rule out $k=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks, it's early and my coffee hasn't taken effect yet.

Comment: @Derek Holt Thanks